# 3D matplotlib figure inside a Spyder terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, mplot3d

I'm plotting a 3D plot in mathplotlib:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, '3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

The figure however open in the terminal so I cannot inspect it. How can I open it in a new window for inspection?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean: *opens in a terminal*?

Comment: @AndreySobolev: the Spyder terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default location for plots is in the *IPython console*. I guess that's what you mean by the terminal?

You can specify where they show up in *Preferences* > *IPython console* > *Graphics* > *Backend*. Change to *Automatic*.

[image: Spyder preferences pane]

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585126/how-do-i-get-interactive-plots-again-in-spyder-ipython-matplotlib) suggests, I had to restart Spyder to get it to pay attention to the change.