# Unable to specify matplotlib backend in Anaconda Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, anaconda, spyder

I would like to manually set the matplotlib backend in Anaconda Spyder using the following commands:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
```

However when I try, I get the following warning, and I can verify that I did not successfully set the backend.

```
>import matplotlib

>matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
/home/selah/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1405: UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
```

If I run ipython from the command line without using Anaconda I can set the backend successfully.

I need to specify the backend in order to successfully run `%matplotlib qt`

Comment: Have you tried [setting the backend via Spyder's menu option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31488324/190597)? (Perhaps you can set it to `qt5agg` (instead of `automatic`) there.)

Comment: I had not.  I can now generate interactive plots.  Thanks!!