# How to change the background color of matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know why there will be a grey frame automatically in my chart. I want to set my chart all white and with a black frame and grid.

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_facecolor('none')
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'none'
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title('Druck')
plt.xlabel('L/D')
plt.ylabel('$Q_{CPT}/Q_{API}$')
plt.ylim((0,4.5))
plt.xlim((0,40))
plt.scatter(x1,y1, c='b', label='UWA-05')
plt.scatter(x2,y2,c='r', label='ICP-05')
plt.grid(axis='y', c='black',alpha=0.8)
plt.grid(axis='x', c='black',alpha=0.8)
plt.legend()
leg = plt.legend()
leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('none')
plt.show()
```

[image: chart with the weird grey frame]

Comment: What platform are you running this code on? When I run it in Spyder as-is I see a black edge, not gray like in your picture.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color ?

Comment: @Brian I use spyder as well...

Comment: Are you using inline graphics? Maybe try using interactive plotting as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31488324/5626104

Comment: @Brian Thanks a lot, this option is 'inline' already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these lines, obviously change the background colour to whatever you want

```
 bg_color = 'black'
 ax1.patch.set_facecolor(bg_color)
```

also change this:

```
leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('Black') #<---- change 'none' to 'Black'
```