# IPython: Alias which uses a magic function itself

Tags: ipython, alias, ipython-magic

I couldn't find anything about this so Im asking here:
I want to create an alias in IPython which itself uses an IPython-magic-function.

That means: I often need to to retype

```
%run process.py
```

thus I'd like to create an alias like this:

```
%alias rp %run process.py
```

the creation works, but when calling `rp`, it says, that the command `%run` could not be found.
Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: Try using a script with the .ipy suffix.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541319/how-to-run-ipython-script-from-the-command-line-syntax-error-with-magic-functi/21542596#21542596

Comment: I dont want to run it on startup, I just want to make the command available..., so where to put the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

When you enter the IPython console, type `%run process.py`

Then you can use the `%macro` magic to bind `rp` to `%run process.py`.

Do so with the `In` storage of inputs.

```
%run process.py
%macro rp In[-2]
```

Should work!

---

`%macro` can also be used to cover a range of inputs, using the syntax `%macro name range` - where range can be an integer or integers in the form start-end.

For instance, if you wanted to time two functions with a single command you can specify the line ranges.

Define functions:

```
In[20]: def foo(x): return x
In[21]: def bar(x): return x*x
```

Time functions:

```
In[22]: %timeit foo(100)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 137 ns per loop
In[23]: %timeit bar(100)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 194 ns per loop
```

Bind macro to name `time_fb`:

```
In[24]: %macro time_fb 22-23
```

Macro bound:

```
Macro `time_fb` created. To execute, type its name (without quotes).
=== Macro contents: ===
get_ipython().magic('timeit foo(100)')
get_ipython().magic('timeit bar(100)')
```

Check it works:

```
In[25]: time_fb
10000000 loops, best of 3: 135 ns per loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 192 ns per loop
```

Comment: The problem with it is, that e.g. warnings are not outputted when using the macro (I fire warnings using `w.warn("blaaaaa")` in my python script.

Comment: @tim - If you put w.filterwarnings("always") at the top of your script, it should always display warnings. There are some more display options [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter). Note that warnings will be displayed each time with 'always'.